# Is removing the relations of a model, in a one-to-many relationship, and redefining the relations the best approach to peform update?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models, user and permissions. 1 user can have many permissions, a user_id will have multiple occurrences on the permissions table. When updating an user I may change its permissions.

```
users         permissions
id            id
name          user_id
```

With eloquent I do something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->permission()->delete();
$user->permission()->create($permissions);
```

Although this code is very logical, it doesn't seem right to me. Finding the user, scanning the table to remove its permissions and reinserting new ones seems amateur, the deletion part doesn't seem right to me. To achieve one task I have to go through multiple processes. 
If at least was something like this:

```
   $user = User::find(1);

  $user->permission()->recreate($permissions);
```

Of course recreate would have to be a built-in function and I am willing to  code that functionality. Can't say if am doing things right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing it rigth?

Since a user can have many permissions, you should have a `user`, `permissions` and a `user_has_permissions` or something like `useR_permissions` table.

```
 users   permissions   user_has_permissions
  id         id              user_id
 name       name           permission_id
  ...        ...
```

This is the relationships:

User permissions (in user model):

```php
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'user_has_permissions');
}
```

To check if the user has permissions (in user model):

```php
public function hasPermission($permissionId)
{
    return null !== $this->permissions()->where('permission_id', $permissionId)->first();
}
```

You can also have a `roles` table, that has many permissions:

```
 users   permissions   user_has_permissions    roles   role_has_permissions   user_has_role
  id         id              user_id             id         role_id              user_id
 name       name           permission_id        name     permission_id           role_id
  ...        ...                                 ...
```

Now, user can have permissions and permissions through roles.

The user roles (in user model):

```php
public function roles()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_has_roles');
}
```

The role permissions (in the Role model):

```php
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'role_has_permissions');
}
```

To check if the user has permissions through roles (in the user model):

```php
public function hasPermissionThroughRoles($permissionId)
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    foreach($roles as $role){
        if($this->roles->contains($permissionId)
             return true;
    }
}
```

You can modify the `hasPermissios` function to check if the user has permission through roles, and if yes, grant access:

```php
public function hasPermission($permissionId)
{
    return (bool)($this->permissions()->where('permission_id', $permissionId)->first() || $this->hasPermissionThroughRoles($permissionId));
}
```

From [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

> Eloquent also provides a few additional helper methods to make working with related models more convenient. For example, let's imagine a user can have many roles and a role can have many users. To attach a role to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins the models, use the attach method.

With the provided code snippets, you can add permission or role to the user with

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->permissions()->attach(1);
$user->roles()->attach(1);
```

or remove permissions/roles:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->permissions()->detach(1);
$user->roles()->detach(1);
```

Check [this package](https://github.com/jungessolutions/laravel-acl). The user permissions and roles (or group, as it is called in the package) management is easy with it.

Hope it helps.